# Can't call method "rs_namespace_uri" on an undefined value at GetRss.pl line 25

Tags: xml, perl, rss, lwp-useragent

I'm working on getting special terminology out of RSS feeds from online news papers. I'm using the XML::RSS::Parser whith LWP::UserAgent for the URL download. I can't get it to work, even though I use pratically a copy paste from cpan : http://search.cpan.org/~tima/XML-RSS-Parser-1.02/Parser.pm#$feed-%3Erss_namespace_uri. I always get the same error : "Can't call method "rss_namespace_uri" on an undefined value at GetRss.pl line 25". I've tried everything... I had the same problem with LWP::Simple and XML::RSS::Parser, and I managed it by using FileHandle, but know I want to get the feeds from multiples sites, saved in an array.
This is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use XML::RSS::Parser;
use URI;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent('XML::RSS::Parser Test Script');
my @places=( 'http://www.timaoutloud.org/xml/index.rdf' );

my $p = new XML::RSS::Parser;

foreach my $place ( @places ) {

         # retreive feed
        my $url=URI->new($place);
        my $req=HTTP::Request->new;
        $req->method('GET');
        $req->uri($url);
        my $feed = $p->parse($ua->request($req)->content);

        # output some values
        my $title = XML::RSS::Parser->ns_qualify('title',$feed->rss_namespace_uri);
        print $feed->channel->type.": ".$feed->channel->element($title)->value."\n";
        print "item count: ".$feed->item_count()."\n";
        foreach my $i ( @{ $feed->items } ) {
                foreach ( keys %{ $i->element } ) {
                        print $_.": ".$i->element($_)->value."\n";
                        }
                        print "\n";
                }
                # data dump of the feed to screen.
                my $d = Data::Dumper->new([ $feed ]);
                print $d->Dump."\n\n";
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you access a resource on the internet, there is always a possibility that this access fails. Do error management:

```
my $response = $ua->get('http://search.cpan.org/');

if ($response->is_success) {
  print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
} else {
  die $response->status_line;
}
```

*— stolen from the [`LWP::UserAgent` documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent)*

Note the use of `decoded_content`, this is better. Also, note the absence of manual request building for a simple `GET`. You will want to replace the `print` with your parsing code.

When I tried to access the URL you gave with my browser, I timed out.

You can also look if the thing that `$p->parse` returned is in fact OK:

```
die "Couldn't parse feed" unless $feed;
```

Also, `use warnings`.

Comment: Thank you very much... It works !!! I'm relatively new to perl so this kind of problems are really hard for me.